# Got some segmentation error when use struct pointer in for loop in C

Tags: c

Here is some simple code that prints struct values

*in_hotel_info* function is used to get struct inputs.(And yes, I use 'gets' because my professor forced me to use it sadly). And also When I put "0" as an input, it ends and returns its input numbers.
And I used sscanf to scan strings and numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct hotel_info hotel;
struct hotel_info
{
    char name[30];
    int rank;
    double popular;
    double far;
    char breakfast;
};
int in_hotel_info(struct hotel_info *p);
void out_hotel_info(struct hotel_info *p, int N, int G, double D);


int main(void)
{
    hotel hotels[100];
    hotel *p;
    int number = 0, ranks, fars, i;
    number = in_hotel_info(hotels);
    p = hotels;
    printf("%d\n", number);
    getchar();
    for (; p < p+number; p++)
    {
        printf("%s %d %lf %lf %c\n", p->name, p->rank, p->popular, p->far, p->breakfast);
    }
}

int in_hotel_info(struct hotel_info infos[])
{
    char inputs[100];
    hotel* p;
    p = infos;
    int cnt = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        gets(inputs);
        if (strcmp(inputs, "0") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sscanf(inputs, "%s %d %lf %lf %c", p->name, &p->rank, &p->popular, &p->far, &p->breakfast);
        }
        p++;
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

The problem is, when I tried to print

```
for (; p < p+number; p++)
    {
        printf("%s %d %lf %lf %c\n", p->name, p->rank, p->popular, p->far, p->breakfast);
    }
```

what I expected is

```
mike 2 3.5 4.24 Y
```

but I constantly got a segmentation error.

Comment: Read documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)..) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Read also the C11 draft standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Consider using [the Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/). With GCC, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is, when I tried to print
>
> ```
> for (; p < p+number; p++)
> {
>     printf("%s %d %lf %lf %c\n", p->name, p->rank, p->popular, p->far, p->breakfast);
> }
> ```

the problem is `p < p+number` is always true when *number* is strictly positive, so the *for* never ends and you access out of the array with an undefined behavior (your segmentation fault).

---

you have additional problems

- *gets* is very dangerous to use because it can write out of the array, use *fgets* or *scanf* (secifying max length to read), in the considered case you can read a number then check if it is 0 or not
- in *in_hotel_info* in case the user enter more than than entrie you write out of the array, you need to get the max number of element to read in argument
- when you read `p->name` in case the enter name longer than 29 you write out of the array, limit the size using `%29s` rather than `%s`. ALso to bypass spaces at the beginning of the name use  `%29s` (with a space before)
- you do not check *scanf* returns 5, so you do not detect invalid inputs

The `getchar();` in *main* is strange